# Unity assets file structure

Tags: unity

I'm writing a map editor for a game built with Unity (5).

I want to reuse as much of the resources from the game as possible. That means textures and meshes.

I know they are somewhere in the assets files, but I need to be able to extract that data during runtime since I cannot (and do not want to) redistribute those files.

Additionally, given that the game receives frequent updates, I need to be able to calculate the offsets each time the editor is started. I also need to know how the textures connect to the objects in the game.

In order to do that, I need to know what the structure of assets file is, or at least find a way to extract them all and then use hex editor to figure out how they're put together.

I know there is a devxdevelopment tool that can do the latter, but I don't really have any money to spend on this.

Can you give me any info or pointers that would enable me to figure this out?

Comment: `I want to reuse as much of the resources from the game as possible.` May I ask the reason behind this? Sounds like premature optimization to me.

Comment: It's a voxel game and I'm creating a map editor. If I don't use the original texture and meshes, it won't be very user-friendly. Besides I want to try to do some more complex stuff and I'll need the original textures in order to make it look right.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you did not develop the original game, but are trying to build a 3rd-party tool to interface with it? Does the game already support some type of external level format that you can target?

Comment: I have already written the code that reads and writes the level format. But I need to display the level in a way that is familiar to the user. As similar as to the game itself. For that I want to use the resources from the game. You'd have to have the game installed to use the program.

Comment: This sounds like a generally bad idea. Unless released under an open source license, the textures will fall under the same license as the original product. Using their artwork without permission is probably copyright infringement. Unless you can prove the license allows for this type of reuse and reverse engineering, I doubt anyone will be comfortable helping you do so.

Comment: I do have permission form the developers to use it in that manner. Besides, the game can only benefit from it. I also thing I'm close to figuring it out myself, I'll post a generic answer here, unless you think that would be bad. There are tool out there that can extract assets from complete Unity games.